# How to parse the data of JSON response in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, facebook-graph-api, nsdictionary

I got a JSON output in this [link](https://graph.facebook.com/419022638150395/photos/)

I extracted the id in this output. (i.e)

419023188150340,
419023228150336,
419023278150331,
419023318150327,
419044998148159,
419045028148156

using the following code

```
[[dict objectForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"id"];
```

dict has the total output that is displayed on the [link](https://graph.facebook.com/419022638150395/photos/)

I displayed this in tableview.
Now if once i tap the cell in tableview. The table should fetch the value of "picture" and display it in console(`NSLog`).

I used the following code to get the response and store it in dictionary(here dict)

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response 
{
    responseData=nil;
    idArray=nil;
    responseData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    idArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];   
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
    [responseData appendData:data];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    dict=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:NULL];
    [idArray addObjectsFromArray:[[dict objectForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"id"]];
    [tableVw reloadData];
}
```

Can any one tell me how to do this.

Comment: Your links return errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You first get a `NSArray` of IDS and you have to loop over it to extract each ID. Try this -

```
NSArray *fbIds = [dict objectForKey:@"data"];
for(NSDictionary *fbId in fbIds)
{
    NSLog("FB ID: %@", [fbID valueForKey:@"id"]);
}
```

Once you extract the correct Facebook_ID, you can use `http://graph.facebook.com/419023188150340/picture` to get your picture. Hope this helps...